# Multiple file upload with the carrierwave_direct gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave_direct gem for uploading files directly to the aws but as it is mentioned on the documentation that only one file can be uploaded at a time, can some one please suggest me a way to upload multiple files at a time.

Comment: So after seeing the implementation of carrierwave_direct gem, I came to understand that what it does is make direct POST request on server with the data so we can't have multiple uploads unless we write some loop. So I reverted back to carrierwave gem which in turn first uploads file to you local temp/uploads folder and then makes the POST request with multiple objects at a time. Later you may delete the local uploads or leave it as it is.